# Subscribing to notifications in Exchange Web Services using Python? (maybe with exchangelib?)

Tags: php, python, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchangelib

Is it possible to subscribe to [EWS Notifications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn458791(v=exchg.150).aspx) using python's `exchangelib` or any other library?

I haven't been able to find how to do it or even if it is possible using Python. I know it is possible with PHP using the `php-ews` library but I rather do the it in Python.

Maybe someone can point me in the right direction?

Comment: `exchangelib` doesn't support this yet: https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib/issues/145